# What is partial trust application?

Tags: .net

Recently I get to touch with partial trust application. Could you explain in some common words? Or give me an example? When should I think about this issue? I am trying to find some documents in the web, but I found very little. So I come to think maybe this is not used often in today's .net programming. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

.NET used a security model called [code access security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28VS.71%29.aspx).

[Partial Trust Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412175.aspx).

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 3.5, partially trusted
>   callers can access public types and methods implemented in
>   System.ServiceModel, System.Runtime.Serialization, and
>   System.ServiceModel.Web. This section describes supported scenarios
>   for using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) within a partially
>   trusted application as well as the limited subset of WCF functionality
>   available to applications running with reduced code access security
>   (CAS) permissions.

Do check this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376049/what-is-a-partially-trusted-assembly-application-code-etc-in-net) and [Programming for Partial Trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364059%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)